# stringstream operator>> stop issues

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code which runs out of my expectation, but I cannot figure out why.

```
stringstream ss1("01"), ss2("1");
int v1, v2;
while (ss1 >> v1 && ss2 >> v2 && v1 == v2) {}
if (ss1 && !ss2)
    cout << 1;
else if (!ss1 && ss2)
    cout << -1; // <== this line will execute
else
    cout << 0;
```

I expected the result would be `cout << 0`, but it executes the line `cout << 1`, which means `!ss1 && ss2` is `true`.

Since `!ss1 && ss2` is `true`, it means `ss2` has not yet stopped. For checking that, I added another two lines so that the code becomes

```
stringstream ss1("01"), ss2("1");
int v1, v2;
while (ss1 >> v1 && ss2 >> v2 && v1 == v2) {}
while (ss2 >> v2)                 // these two lines are added to check 
    cout << "v2: " << v2 << endl; // whether ss2 really goes to the end.
if (ss1 && !ss2)
    cout << 1;
else if (!ss1 && ss2)
    cout << -1;
else
    cout << 0;
```

However, the line `cout << "v2: " << v2 << endl;` didn't run.

So could anyone indicate where the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through the `while` loop:

1. `ss1 >> v1` gets executed, result is `true` (`v1 == 1`)
2. `ss2 >> v2` gets executed, result is `true` (`v2 == 1`)
3. `v1 == v2` gets executed, result is `true`
4. The loop body is executed (nothing happens, it is empty)
5. `ss1 >> v1` gets executed, result is `false`, because there are no more `int`s in `ss1`

This means that the rest of the condition will not get executed, because what's the point? The `while` loop will not repeat, because one value is already `false`. This is called **short circuit evaluation**.

`ss1` failed extraction, so it will return `false`, but `ss2` never tried extraction, so it returns `true`, hence your output: `-1`.